# does Julia package manager update global registry on add operation?

Tags: julia

Whenever one adds a package to the environment, the package manager shows a message that it updates `JuliaRegistries`. My understanding that downloading a package is a read-only operation. Why does Julia say it updates a global registry? Or it is just an indication the local copy of the registry was updated?

```
add Example
Updating registry at `C:\Users\EP\.julia\registries\General`
Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
```

Julia version is 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or it is just an indication the local copy of the registry was updated?

Yes, it is updating your local copy (`C:\Users\EP\.julia\registries\General`) of the remote git repo (`https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`). This happens once per Julia session, on the first Pkg command.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! Also I did not realise it happens once per session.